# variable for string interpolation in a plist file for swift

Tags: swift, plist, string-interpolation

I am looking to see if it is possible to get a string that has a variable in it from a plist.

So just like you would do normally.

```
let string1 = "a string variable"

print("this is \(string1)"
```

I wanted to just put in my plist file `"this is \(string1)"`

So how can you format it in a plist file or can you format it when you pull it out of the plist file into a String.

Or do I just need to rebuild the whole string after I pull it out of the plist file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution would be to use string formatting, not string interpolation.

Put the following value in the plist:

```
this is %@
```

Then load that value as needed. Use it with `String(format:...)`.

```
let format = ... // the format string loaded from the plist
let string1 = "a string variable"
let result = String(format: format, string1)
```

If `format` is `this is %@` then the result will be:

> this is a string variable

Use `%d`, for `Int` variables. Use `%f` for `Double`. See the documentation on [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) for more details on the format specifiers.

Comment: I don't think you should recommend that. As has often been pointed out, a variable format string is a huge security hole. `stringWithFormat` is meant to be used with literal format strings. Your technique works, obviously, but showing it to a beginner and recommending it seems irresponsible somehow.

Comment: @matt I understand you lose compile-time checking when used this way but I'm not aware of the security issue. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: It's something people used to say a lot over on the old Cocoa list at Apple. Even on one of your own answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13696245/341994) it comes up in another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13696242/341994), though of course that's hardly a "reference".

Comment: So can I ask you what would be the safer way to do what I am looking for.  I did some research and it looks like the string with format vulnerability is in conjunction with the print command.  I am not using the print command.  I am filling a text field with the string I am making.

Comment: @EBM I found this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/ValidatingInput.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007246-SW3 There is no security risk with my suggestion because the format strings are not coming from a user or unknown source. You are in control of them.